# can SECEDIT.exe be used to only add 1 group to 1 security policy? example?

Tags: windows, security, groups, lsass

I am assuming based on my research for using SECEDIT.exe -- that a template would be added to the exisitng security .SDB file. That this template would be very tiny... only naming the security policy and and group name -- I can not find documention showing this level of detailed use.

I would appreciate and and all command line examples.

Importantly, I want this group name to be added to the existing list of "members" assigned to the security policy. It is not acceptable to overwrite.

Bottom Line -- I am not sure that SECEDIT.exe has this level of control -- to be able to add just one member name to one security policy.

Also -- as for a usage guide the following about the only thing I have fond that is clear and somewhat helpful. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/solutionbase-using-the-secedit-tool-to-work-with-security-templates/6107195

Thanks in advance.

Kevin Waite